# Split string on punctuation or number in Python

Tags: python, regex, split, numbers, punctuation

I'm trying to split strings every time I'm encountering a punctuation mark or numbers, such as:

```
toSplit = 'I2eat!Apples22becauseilike?Them'
result = re.sub('[0123456789,.?:;~!@#$%^&*()]', ' \1',toSplit).split()
```

The desired output would be:

```
['I', '2', 'eat', '!', 'Apples', '22', 'becauseilike', '?', 'Them']
```

However, the code above (although it properly splits where it's supposed to) removes all the numbers and punctuation marks.

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'\d+|[^\w\s]|_|[^\W\d_]+', toSplit)`

Comment: So, if there is a string like `11!!` you  need to get `['11', '!!']` , right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. I didn't try that case yet, thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Then you may generalize the solution using `re.findall(r'\d+|(?:[^\w\s]|_)+|[^\W\d_]+', toSplit)` to tokenize into digits, letters, and other chars that are not whitespace, letters and digits. I wonder what you would also want to do with `22.45text?!`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may tokenize strings like you have into digits, letters, and other chars that are not whitespace, letters and digits using

```
re.findall(r'\d+|(?:[^\w\s]|_)+|[^\W\d_]+', toSplit)
```

Here,

- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:[^\w\s]|_)+` - 1+ chars other than word and whitespace chars or `_`
- `[^\W\d_]+` - any 1+ Unicode letters.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/clUbMa/1).

Matching approach is more flexible than splitting as it also allows tokenizing complex structure. Say, you also want to tokenize decimal (float, double...) numbers. You will just need to use `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` instead of `\d+`:

```
re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?|(?:[^\w\s]|_)+|[^\W\d_]+', toSplit) 
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/clUbMa/2).

Answer (score 4):

Use `re.split` with capture group:

```
toSplit = 'I2eat!Apples22becauseilike?Them'
result = re.split('([0-9,.?:;~!@#$%^&*()])', toSplit)
result
```

Output:

```
['I', '2', 'eat', '!', 'Apples', '2', '', '2', 'becauseilike', '?', 'Them']
```

If you want to split repeated numbers or punctuation, add `+`:

```
result = re.split('([0-9,.?:;~!@#$%^&*()]+)', toSplit)
result
```

Output:

```
['I', '2', 'eat', '!', 'Apples', '22', 'becauseilike', '?', 'Them']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.split` to split at whenever a alphabet range is found

```
>>> import re                                                              
>>> re.split(r'([A-Za-z]+)', toSplit)                                      
['', 'I', '2', 'eat', '!', 'Apples', '22', 'becauseilike', '?', 'Them', '']
>>>                                                                        
>>> ' '.join(re.split(r'([A-Za-z]+)', toSplit)).split()                    
['I', '2', 'eat', '!', 'Apples', '22', 'becauseilike', '?', 'Them']
```